# How to export an animation from blender to Ethan (third person character) in unity 5

Tags: unity, blender, skeletal-animation

I've made a human animation in blender with the intention of exporting it into unity to add to the animations of the third person character 'Ethan'. Does any one know how I can export the animation into unity for the third person character and make a trigger for the animation?

Answer (score 2):

Well there are two methods which i used but the first would be simpler.
First your human rig's bones must be properly named, if you used the skeleton that comes with Blender instead of a custom one then you are okay.

You simply have to export the animated model to FBX using blender's built in plugin. On the version select 7.4 Binary and leave the rest of the options as is. This assumes the fbx plugin is enabled in blender via the menu options File -> User Preferences -> Addons -> Import-Export:Fbx format.

After that you copy the output fbx file to your unity project folders and import the animation. When you select the fbx model in unity, in the inspector under Rig tab change Animation Type to Humanoid and leave the rest as is then click Apply.

Next, in the Animations tab of the inspector you may need to select the Loop Time option depending on whether your animation should be looped, like a walking or running animation. The rest of the options are usually good on default but experiment and see what you get.

You can then use Ethan's animation controller to add an action for the custom animation and simply drag and drop or assign it to the newly created action. Hopefully that is clear enough.

The second method involves converting the animation to an anim file but after it becomes the same.